# Can't have 2 consts with same name in different files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants, linker-errors

So this actually makes sense to me, but what I find weird is that this "problem" built without issue for a long time until I went to modify a file.

---

I have a ViewController class that defines a constant variable `lineWidth` as

```
const int lineWidth = 2;
```

In another class, called GridView, I define the same constant

```
const int lineWidth = 2;
```

These are both in the .m files of either class. ViewController.h does import GridView.h.

---

This caused no issue at all until today when I went to make a modification to GridView.m. The modification had nothing to do with this constant variable; I was merely adding another constructor to the class. When I built the project, I got this error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker error: duplicate symbol '_lineWidth' in ViewController.o and GridView.o
```

I had never seen this error before.

---

After some trial and error, I was able to get the project to build after changing one of them to `nLineWidth`. Now I think I figured out that the problem was that I was importing GridView.h from ViewController.h, which then imported ViewController.m and GridView.m, both of which had this constant variable defined, causing an error.

### My Question,

however, is why did this build properly up until this point. Is this a new flag that was introduced in XCode 5.1.1? I find it interesting that this wasn't an issue until I started modifying that file. When it needed to rebuild that file, the problem showed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change them both to be:

```
static const int lineWidth = 2;
```

This will make each one specific to the file it is defined in. Each can have its own value without affect the other one. Without `static` they are both declared as app globals and having two with the same name doesn't work.

If you want one shared global then add the following to a .h file:

```
extern const int lineWidth;
```

Then add the following to one (corresponding) .m file:

```
const int lineWidth = 2;
```

This will create a single global that can be used anywhere by importing the .h file.

Comment: And boom! It works. Very nice. Do you have an answer to my question about why this worked until I modified the file? This project was originally built in XCode 4.

Comment: Strange. Well thanks for the info! Now I won't make that mistake again! :)